# Is there some template engine like mustache, but which targets CSS?

Tags: html, css, templates, template-engine

Shouldn't be useful to have templated CSS? Let's say for example I want to decide at run time the class names of my CSS, or wich id to apply the template CSS to. It should be feasible in practice, parsing CSS is relatively easy and injecting / removing classes at runtime can be done. Is there a projects which does that?

Comment: What would be the benefit of such a system?

Comment: Dinamically injecting plugins with their CSS, for example.